# Is it possible to reset static field after function end or out of the scope?

Tags: c#

I have multiple type of Component class and 1 generator class. Component class has a name field and it must be unique when generated by the generator class.

So, I write the component class and generator class as below:

```
public class Component_A{
    static int iCount;
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Component_A(){
        name = String.Format("ComponentA_{0}", iCount++);
    }
}

public class Component_B{
    static int iCount;
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Component_A(){
        name = String.Format("ComponentB_{0}", iCount++);
    }
}

public class Generator(){
    public List<String> generateComponent(){
        Component_A a1 = new Component_A();
        Component_A a2 = new Component_A();
        Component_B b1 = new Component_B();

        List<string> strList = new List<string>();
        strList.Add(a1.name);
        strList.Add(a2.name);
        strList.Add(b1.name);

        return strList;
    }
}

public class MainClass(){
    public static void main(){
        Generator gen;
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            gen = new Generator();
            List<String> componentNameList = gen.generateComponent();

            foreach(var s in componentNameList){
                Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.Out.WriteLine();
        }

    }
}
```

However, i want to reset the component iCount field when the new generator is initialized.

For example: the above code execution result is:

```
ComponentA_0
ComponentA_1
ComponentB_0

ComponentA_2
ComponentA_3
ComponentB_1
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
ComponentA_0
ComponentA_1
ComponentB_0

ComponentA_0
ComponentA_1
ComponentB_0
```

How can I able to achieve this?

Comment: How about adding a method in your Generator class to reset the `iCount`s? Something like `gen.reset()` which will just assign 0 to respective `iCount`s.

Comment: try reset `iCount` at the end of looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Component_A{
    public static int iCount;
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Component_A(){
        name = String.Format("ComponentA_{0}", iCount++);
    }
}

public class Component_B{
    public static int iCount;
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Component_A(){
        name = String.Format("ComponentB_{0}", iCount++);
    }
}

public class Generator(){
    public List<String> generateComponent(){
        Component_A a1 = new Component_A();
        Component_A a2 = new Component_A();
        Component_B b1 = new Component_B();

        List<string> strList = new List<string>();
        strList.Add(a1.name);
        strList.Add(a2.name);
        strList.Add(b1.name);

        return strList;
    }
    public void reset() {
        Component_A.iCount = 0;
        Component_B.iCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Just changed `iCount` to public and added a reset method to change the `iCount`s to 0.

Use it like this:

```
public class MainClass(){
    public static void main(){
        Generator gen;
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            gen = new Generator();
            List<String> componentNameList = gen.generateComponent();

            foreach(var s in componentNameList){
                Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
            }
            gen.reset();
            Console.Out.WriteLine();
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: Since you have 100s of components, reflection seems to be a nice choice. I've moved the components in their own class.

```
public class Components{
    public class Component_A{
        public static int iCount;
        public string name {get;set;}
        public Component_A(){
            name = String.Format("ComponentA_{0}", iCount++);
        }
    }

    public class Component_B{
        public static int iCount;
        public string name {get;set;}
        public Component_B(){
            name = String.Format("ComponentB_{0}", iCount++);
        }
    }
}

public class Generator {
    public List<String> generateComponent(){
        var a1 = new Components.Component_A();
        var a2 = new Components.Component_A();
        var b1 = new Components.Component_B();

        List<string> strList = new List<string>();
        strList.Add(a1.name);
        strList.Add(a2.name);
        strList.Add(b1.name);

        return strList;
    }
    public void reset() {
        var components = typeof(Components).GetNestedTypes().ToList();
        foreach (var component in components) {
            var property = component.GetField("iCount", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
            property.SetValue(null, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its work. However, what if I have hundred of Component class, do I need to add it one by one in reset()?

Comment: If you've got 100s of such components, a better idea would be to have an abstract class with reset method setting `iCount` to 0. Then all the components inheriting that abstract class. That way, you will have `Component_A.reset()` automatically. Let me know if you want a sample.

Comment: I've added a reset example which should scale (in terms of code) even if you've got 100s of components. You should look into object creation by reflection if you want to minimize your `generator` method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having components responsible for naming themselves, I'd create a `NameGenerator` class that is given a root and (optionally) starting number, that exposes `NextName`:

```
public class NameGenerator {
    private int _next;
    private readonly string _nameRoot;
    public NameGenerator(string nameRoot) : this (nameRoot, 0)
    {}
    public Namegenerator(string nameRoot, int firstNumber)
    {
        _next = firstNumber;
        _nameRoot = nameRoot;
    }
    public string NextName()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}_{1}", _nameRoot,_next++);
    }
}
```

Your `Generator` class should now own a set of these objects (up to you whether to initialize these eagerly or lazily), and your `Component` class's should have a constructor accepting the names that the `NameGenerator` is spitting out.

```
public class Component_A{
    public string name {get;private set;}
    public Component_A(string name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: That mean I have to initialize 1 NameGenerator() for each type of Component? If I have hundred of component class, then I need initialize hundred of nameGenerator()?

Comment: Yes, you would use one NameGenerator for each sequence of names. Or put it another way - you've already got these hundreds of name generators in your current setup. But they're hidden away because they're not a named class; their *properties* are embedded in each of your `Component` classes and the logic is being *reimplemented* each time.

Comment: @ZhengJieTan - and your problem has arisen because you now want to change the state of these embedded name generators, but because they're not really exposed in your current model, that makes it difficult to see.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're willing to count the A or B components generated by each instance of generator instead of just counting the total number of components A or B.

So you should put the counters in the generator instance :

```
public class Component_A{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Component_A(int count){
        name = String.Format("ComponentA_{0}",  count);
    }
}
public class Component_B{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Component_B(int count){
        name = String.Format("ComponentB_{0}", count);
    }
}
public class Generator{
    private int iCountA=0;
    private int iCountB=0;
    private Component_A createComponentA()
    {
        return new Component_A(iCountA++);
    }
    private Component_B createComponentB()
    {
        return new Component_B(iCountB++);
    }
    public List<String> generateComponent(){
        Component_A a1 = createComponentA();
        Component_A a2 = createComponentA();
        Component_B b1 = createComponentB();
        List<string> strList = new List<string>();
        strList.Add(a1.name);
        strList.Add(a2.name);
        strList.Add(b1.name);
        return strList;
    }
}
```

Here's the output (main code remains unchanged) :

```
ComponentA_0
ComponentA_1
ComponentB_0

ComponentA_0
ComponentA_1
ComponentB_0
```